# SNMP (net-snmp) is missing 64 bit counters on FreeBSD 9.1 (ifHCInOctets/ifHCOutOctets)

Tags: freebsd, snmp

I am using SNMP (from the port net-mgmt/net-snmp, v5.7.2, compiled with "MFD_REWRITES") on a FreeBSD9.1-RELEASE system. For some reason, the ifXTable MIB (1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1) seems to be missing the HC counters (like `ifHCInOctets` (1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.6) for example).

```
get (noSuchName) There is no such variable name in this MIB.
snmpget localhost <hostname> 1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.6.5
snmpget localhost <hostname> ifHCInOctets.5
snmp error index = 1
```

And when listing 1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1 I get

```
usbus0 ifName.1
...
vr0 ifName.5
...
re0 ifName.8
...
re0.10 ifName.12
...
tun0 ifName.17
...
79144352 ifInMulticastPkts.5
...
120009 ifInMulticastPkts.8
...
43670 ifInMulticastPkts.12
...
0 ifInBroadcastPkts.5
...
0 ifOutMulticastPkts.5
...
0 ifOutBroadcastPkts.5
...
100 ifHighSpeed.5
...
1000 ifHighSpeed.8
...
false ifPromiscuousMode.5
...
true ifConnectorPresent.5
...
 ifAlias.5
...
0:00:00 ifCounterDiscontinuityTime.5
...
```

To me it seems as if "a lot" was there. But not the `ifHC[In|Out]Octets`...

As you can see my interfaces use the "vr" (Via Rhine) and "re" (Realtek). Does anyone have a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that the problem seems to be my querying: for some (unknown) reason the perl module `SNMP::Util` that I am using unconditionally submits SNMP queries using protocol version 1. And SNMP v1 cannot handle 64-bit counters.

So I tried using `Net::SNMP::Util` instead which let's you specify the SNMP protocol version to use. And voilà, it works.

Using `snmpwalk` from the shell also reveals this:

```
$ snmpwalk -Os -c <community> -v 1 localhost 1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1 | grep 'ifHC.*Octets' |wc -l
   0
$ snmpwalk -Os -c <community> -v 2c localhost 1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1 | grep 'ifHC.*Octets' |wc -l
  34
$ snmpwalk -Os -c <community> localhost 1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1 | grep 'ifHC.*Octets' |wc -l
  34
```